# In InDesign how do I change the gap between spreads?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, cc-2015

I didn't see this Q&A here so I thought I would share.  So a colleague sent me an InDesign file with a huge gap between the spreads but how can I adjust this gap so it makes the file easier to work with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To adjust the gap between the spreads in InDesign you will need to navigate to `Guides & Pasteboard...`

To navigate to this you will go to `InDesign -> Preferences -> Guides & Pasteboard...`:

[image]

A panel will appear:

[image]

Adjust the `Vertical Margins`:

[image]

click the button `OK` and you should see your adjustment:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I figured this out quite by accident and because of another issue I was having with exporting my PDF file with it giving a background task error.

The answer is in your layers panel. Just select all the design elements on your page, then look in your layers panel. Everything you've selected should be highlighted, if you see any layer that's not highlighted then bingo! Those layers are the cause of the problems. Just click on them and delete. 2 issues solved at once.

I hope this works for anyone else who was having this annoying issue.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question.